# How to unblock an app blocked due to publishing events on rabbitmq server having disk space issues?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq java client to publish events from my java application. 
When the server goes out of space, all the publish messages are blocked. 
In my application, I am ok with events not being published but, I want the application to continue to work. To that end I looked at the documentation and found BlockedListener on the connection[1]

I was able to use this. But, the problem is unless I throw a runtime exception in the handleBlocked method, my app/publisher is still blocked. I tried to close/abort the connection but, nothing worked.

Is there any other graceful way to unblock my app

This is my BlockedListener code

```
private class BlockedConnectionHandler implements BlockedListener {

    @Override
    public void handleBlocked(String reason) throws IOException {
        s_logger.error("rabbitmq connection is blocked with reason: " + reason);
        throw new RuntimeException("unblocking the parent thread");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleUnblocked() throws IOException {
        s_logger.info("rabbitmq connection in unblocked");
    }
}
```

[1] https://www.rabbitmq.com/connection-blocked.html

Comment: As far as I understand this, I guess `handleBlocked` is executed on a different Thread than the blocked one - quite obvious. So throwing an exception here does nothing to the blockage. You have to interrupt the blocked Thread - hoping that RabbitMQ's sendMessage supports Interruption. Maybe the docs can tell you that.

Comment: when I throw an exception, I am able to unblock the application thread. my question is there any other graceful way to notify the parent thread?